# How to return data from Promises if second fetch request depends on first?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch-api, redux-toolkit

I want to get some data from 2 apis, but i need some properties from the first api to make the fetch request to the second api. I also need the entire response from the first api.

```
export const fetchTrip = createAsyncThunk(
    'trip/fetchTrip',
    async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
        const result = fetch(
            'http://localhost:5000/user/trip/' + payload, {
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include',
            method: "get",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())

        .then(data => {
            const places= data.trips[0].places
            return Promise.all(places.map(place=>
                fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/tripadvisor/' + place.id)
                ))
                .then(resp => resp.json())
        })
        console.log(result)
        return result
    }
)
```

So the first fetch request will respond with some data such as

```
{
    title: "Cali Trip",
    budget: "1000",
    places: [
        {id: "123"}, 
        {id: "234"}, 
        {id: "345"}
    ]
}
```

I am using the place's `id` to fetch more details about that place. in the end, i want to return the trip detail from the first api, and all the details of the multiple places from the second api. I've tried the above code, but my `response` is undefined. ty in advance for any help!!

Comment: I bet if you replace `}) console.log(result)` with `}).then(result => console.log(result))` it will work better - oh, and `return result` will return the Promise regardless of what you do

Comment: Why does your first request appear to respond with a singleton array?

Comment: can you update the promise all and check , return Promise.all(places.map(place=>
                fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/tripadvisor/' + place.id).then(resp => resp.json();)
                )).then(resp => {
     console.log(resp)
   })

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already making the function async, you could use await to make it more easy to follow, something along these lines, just a sketch for you to elaborate:

```js
export const fetchTrip = createAsyncThunk(
  'trip/fetchTrip',
  async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/user/trip/' + payload, {
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then((resp) => resp.json());

    // here your first result
    console.log(data);

    const places = data.trips[0].places;
    const result = await Promise.all(
      places.map((place) =>
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/tripadvisor/' + place.id).then(
          (resp) => resp.json()
        )
      )
    );

    // here the second result
    console.log(result);

    // overwrite places with second result
    return {
      ...data,
      places: result,
    };
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a lot cleaner if you didn't mix `async / await` with `.then()`.

What you can do is return the response from the first request with the `places` array re-assigned with the values resolved from the secondary requests.

```js
export const fetchTrip = createAsyncThunk(
  "trip/fetchTrip",
  async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:5000/user/trip/${encodeURIComponent(payload)}`,
      {
        credentials: "include", // cookies? Do you even need this?
      }
    );

    if (!res.ok) { // don't forget to check for failures
      throw res;
    }

    // pull out the first "trip" from the "trips" array
    const {
      trips: [{ places, ...trip }],
    } = await res.json();

    // respond with the "trip"
    return {
      ...trip,

      // resolve "places" by mapping the array to a new promise
      // and awaiting its result
      places: await Promise.all(
        places.map(async ({ id }) => {
          const placeRes = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:5000/api/tripadvisor/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`
          );
    
          // again, check for errors
          if (!placeRes.ok) {
            throw placeRes;
          }

          // resolve with the place data
          return placeRes.json();
        })
      ),
    };
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing `async`/`await` code with Promise chaining code. While that's certainly valid, if we clean up your code a bit you can see that this is trivially done if you convert all of your code to `async`/`await`:

```js
const response1 = await fetch('...');
const data1 = await response.json();
const data2 = await Promise.all([...]);
```

Of course, this can be done with Promise chaining by saving the data from inner calls into a variable outside the calls, but that's a far inferior option:

```js
let data1;
let data2;

fetch('...')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    data1 = data;
    
    return Promise.all([...]);
  })
```

Comment: @Phil bad copy pasta, thanks!